Fitting a Multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process to Data
I have multivariate time series data (100 dimensions or more) and wish to test the hypothesis that the dynamics follow a Langevin equation. A simple case is the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process, how can one estimate the parameters of such a multivariate process from the given dataset and test the goodness of fit?

Hi: In the univariate case, the discrete version of an OU is an AR(2). But I don't know if that carries over to the multivariate case. It's worth looking into though.

I know nothing about the paper and whether it makes a connection to the AR(2) but it's possible that you don't need to make that connection. This says that there is an R package that estimates these type of models. I don't know what the methodology is but the paper should be useful.  https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.14376

Surprisingly clicking the pdf worked also !!!!! I assumed it would send me to some "you are not subscribed" site. It didn't.

@mlofton The autocovariance function of a univariate OU-process has exponential decay so if it is observed at regularly spaced discrete time points you will have an AR(1) process.

oops. it must be AR(1) then. I'll make sure but it was on memory so I tend to believe you. The final thing I sent I don't think has anything to do with the AR anyway so it's still hopefully useful. Thanks for correction.

@Jarle Tufto: This shows what you said so I believe you even more now !!!! Thanks for correction.  ksheen: apologies for confusion.  https://people.tamu.edu/~roiterst/papers/arde.pdf
